# MySQL - Slow query execution even with relevant indexes

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have this query executing forever. I am unable to understand where the problem is. Any idea on this would be of great help!!

```
select (case when fca.CompletionDate = '1900-01-01'
             then null
             else fca.CompletionDate end) CompletionDate,
    fca.IsClosed,
    fca.LastModifiedDate,
    fca.isactive,    
    fca.ExpectedStartDate,
    fca.ExpectedClosureDate,
    ai.activityscheduleid,
    fca.activityscheduleid
from activityinformation ai
join FarmerCropActivity fca 
    on ai.activityscheduleid = fca.activityscheduleid 
    and fca.isactive = 1
```

The plan is as as below

http://i65.tinypic.com/2rxwjk2.png

The table details are as below

http://i68.tinypic.com/14nldw0.png

select count(*) from activityinformation; -- 117270

select count(*) from FarmerCropActivity where isactive =1; -- 1488477

Thanks
Rathi

Comment: try adding a limit, what it's currently trying to do is load 117270 rows at once - pretty big amount of data.

Comment: It was working all this while in a matter of few minutes, within 5 -7 minutes. I need all the data. This slowness started from today morning

Comment: Ah I see, is it possble there's a new row with a field with a long data string? try monitoring sql queries in general and see if there is an overall increase in execute time - could be all queries, not just this one

Comment: did you have that `CASE` in your query all that time? because the issue to me is that *calculation* in each row

Comment: I can see in SHOW PROCESSLIST, that this is the only one stuck at Sending data. The CASE was always present.

Comment: is there backend code that executes the query? like PHP or is it just SQL queries from terminal?

Comment: It is executed through a procedure, which in-turn is called from Talend(ETL)

Comment: Nothing in the first png.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; too much info is missing.

Comment: Are the tables in 1:many relationship?  Vice versa?  What?